# Are all dog whistles created equal?

Tags: dogs, behavior, vocalizations

I have just been browsing Amazon's listings for dog whistles, and found the vast number of choices to be quite surprising. I'm now wondering if "you get what you pay for" would apply in this situation. If so, then I would spend more for a higher end product.  But, since I know nothing on the subject, have doubts about whether there is much of a difference in the performance of one product over another.  I am not concerned about durability or appearance.

To avoid asking a subjective question, I am hoping that someone has had enough experience over time, in situations where dog whistles were used or in conversations with other users on the subject, to say that the results produced are noticeably different depending on the whistle being used. If so, what type, style, feature, brand(!), aspect or other property of the dog whistle makes it perform the best and by how much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't claim much experience but did some research on this recently when buying my first one. There seem to be 3 basic kinds:

(1) Fancy steel whistle with adjustable frequencies or other premium whistles etc
(2) Mid-market plastic whistles with choice of set frequencies
(3) Cheap plastic whistle.

The price difference between (2) and (3) is not that much, so went with an Acme Dog Whistle which seems to be the leading brand.

Anyway, the dog can hear it and sometimes obeys it. Not sure if the cheaper ones would be just a good but there was only c. £2 price differnet (£4 vs £6) so didn't bother to find out.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for the reply it was helpful  I tried to give you an up vote but don't have that power yet to be bestowed upon my wretched account yet!  In fact, even this "thank you" note is illicit behavior! I'm usually respectful of rules except when they are oppressive to basic human self respect and dignity that I can't even express a positive gesture to another human being who was kind enough to help out. Thanks again! peace